# At wit's end with NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So, my assignment is to write a program that accepts student names and grades, and utilizes multiple arrays. I've rewritten the section of code throwing the runtime error several times in different ways, but with the same NullPointerException error. I have run tests to print the contents of the array to the console, but have yet to actually see it return "null". So I'm at a lost here...

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at GradeBook.setScoreArray(GradeBook.java:41)
    at GradeBookApp.main(GradeBookApp.java:72)
```

GradeBookApp(main):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GradeBookApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //constants
        final int NUM_STUDENTS = 2;
        final int NUM_SCORES = 4;

        //variables
        double myAverage;
        char myLetter;
        String myStudent;

        //arrays
        double[][] scoreArray = new double[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_SCORES];
        String[] studentArray = new String[NUM_STUDENTS];


        //initialize scanner
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int n = 0; n < NUM_STUDENTS; n++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of student #" + (n+1) + ": ");
            studentArray[n] = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++)
        {

            //adds VALID individual test scores to the array
            for (int s = 0; s < NUM_SCORES; s++)
            {
                double scoreHolder = 0;

                do
                {
                    System.out.print("Enter test score #" + (s+1) + " for '" + studentArray[i] + "': ");
                    scoreHolder = keyboard.nextDouble();

                    if (scoreHolder > 100 || scoreHolder < 0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("***  SCORES MUST BE FROM 0-100 ONLY!  ***");
                    }

                } while(scoreHolder > 100 || scoreHolder < 0);

                scoreArray[i][s] = scoreHolder;
                //System.out.println(scoreHolder + " was added to position: " + i + "," + s);
            }
            System.out.println(" ");

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(scoreArray)); //This works as intended

        GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook(NUM_SCORES, NUM_STUDENTS);
        for (int index = 0; index < NUM_STUDENTS; index++)
        {
            for (int score = 0; score < NUM_SCORES; score++)
            {
                myGradeBook.setScoreArray(scoreArray[index][score]);
            }
        }
        for (int student = 0; student < NUM_STUDENTS; student++)
        {
            myGradeBook.setStudentArray(studentArray[student]);
        }

        //for each student...
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STUDENTS; i++)
        {
            //calculate average

            myAverage = myGradeBook.getGradeAvg(i);
            //calculate letter grade

            myLetter = myGradeBook.getLetterGrade(myAverage);
            //get student name for display

            myStudent = myGradeBook.getStudentName(i);

            //display results
            System.out.println(myStudent + "'s final score is: " + myAverage + " (" + myLetter + ")");
        }

    }
}
```

GradeBook(class):

```
public class GradeBook {

    private String[] studentNames;
    private char[] letterGrades = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F' };
    private double[][] studentScores;
    private int numStudents;
    private int numScores;


    public GradeBook(int NUM_SCORES, int NUM_STUDENTS)
    {
        numStudents = NUM_STUDENTS;
        numScores = NUM_SCORES;
    }


    public void setStudentArray(String students)
    {
        //set the student array
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            studentNames[i] = students;
        }
    }

    public void setScoreArray(double scores)
    {
        //for each student...
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
        {
            //set each individual score
            for (int s = 0; s < numScores; s++)
            {
                studentScores[i][s] = scores;
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStudentName(int pos)
    {
        return studentNames[pos];
    }

    public double getGradeAvg(int pos)
    {
        double total = 0;
        double avg = 0;

        //use the position variable to iterate over the correct test scores...
        for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++)
        {
            total += studentScores[pos][i];
        }

        avg = total / numScores;
        return avg;
    }

    public char getLetterGrade(double average)
    {
        char letter = 'Z';

        if (average >= 0 && average < 60)
        {
            letter = letterGrades[4];
        }
        else if (average > 60 && average < 70)
        {
            letter = letterGrades[3];
        }
        else if (average > 70 && average < 80)
        {
            letter = letterGrades[2];
        }
        else if (average > 80 && average < 90)
        {
            letter = letterGrades[1];
        }
        else if (average > 90 && average <= 100)
        {
            letter = letterGrades[0];
        }

        return letter;
    }



}
```

Every thing I can find says that I'm referencing a null value? But I've gone as far as to manually set all of the scores to 90 through a loop, and still get the same result. I'm at a lost for where to go from here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: For clarification, I have added the entire code, instead of snippets. I have also, since, added Arrays.toDeepString to test the array, the values are printed to the console as intended.

Comment: How and where `studentScores` is initialized?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Did you initialize `studentScores` because if that's a `null`, evidently you can't access the `[i]`...

Comment: It would be most useful to see the entire class as a reference, there may be something incorrect elsewhere that causes the flag here.

Comment: GradeBook myGradeBook = new GradeBook(NUM_SCORES, NUM_STUDENTS); does -not- declare it as a specific value. You may want to declare the following as a global: double NUM_SCORE = 0; and int NUM_STUDENT = 0; (This means to declare it outside any public void foo() methods, or main, but under public class foo().

Comment: **Where did you create the `studentScores` array??**

Comment: (Note that "declare" is not the same as "create".)

Comment: Please post a stack trace, and reduce the code to the minimum runnable example.

Comment: Whenever you post about getting an exception, always, always, always post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `studentScores` with `private double[][] studentScores;`, but you don't initialize is anywhere. It's a null pointer until you initialize it. You can do this in the constructor, when you know its dimensions:

```
studentScores = new double[numStudents][numScores];
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea I could initialize in the constructor, and assumed that the number of elements would be automatic when I assigned values from the main program. Maybe I should've considered ArrayLists.